# Is SharePoint's Record Management certified to any standard?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, records-management, ecm

Is SharePoint's Record Management certified to any standard?

Standards like the U.S. Department of Defense (DoD) 5015.02.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint per se, it is not actually buit to follow the exact regulations for a particular standard but it does confer capabilities to support many standards, through the actual solution built on top of it, for which there are many, such as http://sharepointrecordsmanagement.com/tag/sharepoint-2010-dod-5015-2-certification/.

If you read at AIIM, you'll understand better http://www.aiim.org/community/blogs/expert/DoD-50152-Certification-and-SharePoint-2010 & http://www.aiim.org/community/blogs/expert/5-myths-about-sharepoint-records-management

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have also published a case study in regards to SP2010 being used by the US Department of Agriculture.  It can be found here: -

http://www.microsoft.com/casestudies/Case_Study_Detail.aspx?CaseStudyID=4000009950

Answer (score 0):

So far as I understand it's not certified to any standard, but there's at least one third-party solution that is certified 5015.02, and others that are enough for most needs. I went to a talk by Bruce Miller on the subject a couple months ago - here are some of his points:

http://www.rimtech.ca/Microsoft_SharePoint.html